# Error found while opening excel file downloaded from a blob field in Oracle Database using Access VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have following code which downloads data stored in a blob field in a linked Oracle table to a file. The blob data stores excel file (.xlsx) but when I try to open the downloaded file in excel, I get an error saying the file is corrupted and not in proper format. Here's the code -

```
Option Explicit
Const BlockSize = 32768

Public Function DownloadBlob()
  Dim db As Database
  Dim rst As Recordset
  Dim NumBlocks As Integer, DestFile As Integer, i As Integer
  Dim FileLength As Long, LeftOver As Long
  Dim FileData, FilePath As String
  Dim RetVal As Variant

  Set db = CurrentDb
  Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("Select Blob_Field FROM Table1;")

  NumBlocks = FileLength / BlockSize
  LeftOver = FileLength Mod BlockSize

  DestFile = FreeFile()
  FilePath = "C:\Desktop\test.xlsx"

  Open FilePath For Output As DestFile
  Close DestFile

  Open FilePath For Binary As DestFile
    FileData = rst.Fields(0).GetChunk(0, LeftOver)
    Put DestFile, , FileData
    For i = 1 To NumBlocks
        FileData = rst.Fields(0).GetChunk((i - 1) * BlockSize + LeftOver, BlockSize)
        Put DestFile, , FileData
    Next i
Close DestFile
End Function
```

Comment: You have `Const BlockSize = 32768` at the top of the file, right? And no issues when extracting the file through the GUI?

Comment: You're in Access, DB is limited to 2GB. Why waste precious storage space for something that can perfectly well live on a file server?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't being clearer before, as I stated in the title, the table is a linked table in Oracle Database and thus the 2GB limit does not apply and I only have RO access to that database and have to download those excel files.

Comment: So the original files don't exist anymore?

Comment: Unrelated: why are you opening and then closing and then opening the `FilePath`?

Comment: Most of his code comes from https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/210486/acc2000-reading--storing--and-writing-binary-large-objects-blobs, where the same technique is used. The first opening and closing overwrites any file located at `FilePath` with a blank copy, so the second can append to that.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Of course, I get that. Don't you think `If Dir(file) <> vbNullString Then Kill file` does a better job at conveying what's going on and why though?

Comment: @Mat'sMug perfectly valid questions, your way is obviously more explicit, but it's a Microsoft sample from 2006, so who knows? Making sure you overwrite when you output a file isn't a bad practice imho though.

Comment: OP you still haven't answered my first comment. Your code might be fully functional (at least I haven't spotted an error), but the file might just be corrupt. As Mat'sMug noted, there's a chance of data corruption when storing files in BLOBs.

Comment: @ Erik von Asmuth, I was following microsoft documentation while using the block size since and I am not very familiar with the concept of block size

Comment: Are you certain the stored file is in xlsx format, and not some other file type?  If that's not the issue then you might have better luck using ADO and writing the file via a Stream object: that way you can skip the whole chunking thing.

Comment: @Sn_Srm that really isn't clear. The documentation states that the top of the module should contain `Option Explicit` and `Const BlockSize = 32768`. Does it or doesn't it in your case? Because if it doesn't, this code will generate corrupt files.

Comment: @ Erik von Asmuth, my code does contain those parts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @TimWilliams commented nested within the long thread, consider using [ADO Stream object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/stream-object-ado) to extract the data from the recordset field value. Below demonstrates with ADO, a different DB-API, than what you were using with Access' default DB-API, DAO. But you may be able to still use a DAO recordset in the ADO stream object.

```
Public Function DownloadBlob()
   ' ENABLE REFERENCE: Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects X.X Library
   Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection, rs AS New ADODB.Recordset
   Dim stm As New ADODB.Stream
   Dim strFile As String

   strFile = "C:\Desktop\test.xlsx"

   conn.Open "<Connection String To Oracle>"
   rs.Open "SELECT Blob_Field FROM Table1", conn 

   With stm
      .Open
      .Type = adTypeBinary
      .Write rs.Fields("Blob_Field").Value
      .SaveToFile strFile
      .Close
   End With 

   rs.Close: conn.Close

ExitHandle:
   Set stm = Nothing: Set rs = Nothing: Set conn = Nothing

ErrHandle:
   Msgbox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description, vbCritical
   Resume ExitHandle    
End Function
```

The beauty too of this DAO to ADO switch is this VBA code can work in any Office application including Excel as it absolves any MS Access object (i.e, linked table, DAO). And for that matter, even beyond VBA to any COM-connected library (Java's `jacob`, Python's `win32com`, R's `RDCOMClient`, PHP's `COM`).

Comment: I'm pretty sure that an ADODB.Stream object can be used to store and retrieve BLOB data from a DAO.Recordset, so using the ADODB.Stream object does not *require* that the connection and recordset be changed from DAO to ADODB.

Comment: Thanks @GordThompson...I changed the *require* line.